# Universal Add method

Tags: c#, .net, collections, covariance

I want to create a method that is able to **add an item to a collection** whose type is unknown at compile time. It will receive two objects: the collection and the item.

Currently, I have this:

```
public void Add(object collection, object item) 
{
      var list = (IList)collection;
      list.Add(item);
}
```

The problem? It doesn't work when the collection is a, for example, an instance of this type:

```
public sealed class ColumnDefinitionCollection : IList<ColumnDefinition>, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> 
{
}
```

What can I do to make it work with every kind of instance that has an Add method?

**EDIT:** I'm tried with the method proposed by @lukegv, but I'm getting this when the collection is a `ColumnDefinitionCollection` (running in a Universal Windows Application):

[image]

I created another question related to this issue ("Add" not being retrieved) [Unable to get the "Add" method of a ColumnDefinitionCollection in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986903/not-able-to-get-the-add-method-of-a-type?noredirect=1#comment67254358_39986903)

Comment: Do you expect it to work for `TimeSpan.Add` as well? Just to hint that the presence of an `Add` method probably isn't *all* you care about...

Comment: Why not just try to cast to `ICollection<T>`? Or are you trying to implement duck typing?

Comment: Actually, every "kind of instance that has an Add method" should be based on `ICollection<T>`. Otherwise, you have no idea, what or how many parameters are expected by the method, eg. in `TimeSpan.Add` or `Dictionary.Add`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point. I would like to use an Add method ONLY if it means "to associate a child to a parent"

Comment: @SuperJMN But you also need to know the number of parameters expected by the `Add()` method.

Comment: And how do you expect to determine whether that's what the method does?

Comment: why don't you just want to check for a `IList` type?

Comment: @DStanley Not, it's for my OmniXAML parser (version 2). When a property that is 1xN (one-to-many), child instances in the XAML are added to it. It's the most abstract interpretation of parent-child relationship and I feel that there's no interface that fits every case.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I don't have a good way to determine that. I supposed that there may be one interface that encapsulates the behavior of a one-to-many relationship, but now that I face the case, generics, covariance and castings are killing me! :)

Comment: @lukegv I did that in my current implementation (in the original post), but it doesn't work with instances like class MyCollection : IList<MyClass>, IEnumerable<MyClass> (throws an InvalidCastException)

Comment: For cases like class MyCollection : IList<MyClass>, IEnumerable<MyClass> - do you control the original class? If so, could you modify it to implement ICollection<T> (or some other interface of your own devising)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Unfortunately, I don't have control above that. The types of the instances that will come are huge and the meaning will always be the same, a collection and a child to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to extend Zdravko Danevs answer by some checks to prevent undesired behavior like the one you and Jon Skeet mentioned (`DateTime.Add`).
This one checks whether the type expected by the collections `Add`-method equals the type provided by the item.

```
static void AddToCollection(object collection, object item)
{
    MethodInfo addMethod = collection.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
    if (addMethod == null || addMethod.GetParameters().Length != 1)
    {
        // handle your error
        return;
    }
    ParameterInfo parameter = addMethod.GetParameters().First();
    if (parameter.ParameterType.Equals(item.GetType()))
    {
        addMethod.Invoke(collection, new object[] { item });
    }
    else
    {
        // handle your error
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and strangely enough, it doesn't work when the type is a ColumnDefinitionCollection. My code is running into a PCL. Please, take a look to the original post that I'm going to edit to include more details. Thank you!

Comment: To add some more information, it doesn't work in UWP, either. It seems the GetRuntimeMethods doesn't get the Add method (it also happens with the Contains method)

Comment: Actually, this suprises me. I could not reproduce your problem, because I dont have .NET Core installed. If I try this method on `System.Windows.Controls.ColumnDefinitionCollection` (from FrameworkElement), it works like a charm. Just a small question: What are the other types beside `ColumnDefinitionCollection` you want to use the desired method on.

Comment: Yes, it works for WPF, but it doesn't work with the equivalent type in UWP. Maybe reflection works differently in there! Anyways, I haven't figured out how to get the MethodInfo of "Add" in this situation yet.

Answer (score 0):

While this is probably not what you want to do, you can use reflection to check if there is an Add method and call it with the parameter supplied. Something like this (untested):

```
Type t = collection.GetType();
MethodInfo add = t.GetMethod("Add");
if (add != null)
{
    params = new object[] { item };
    add.Invoke(collection, params);
}
```

Comment: That should work! but I'm afraid that I will get an undesired behavior for types like DateTime (it has an Add method that is semantically different).

Comment: I completely agree (s)he should not be doing that. it is more of an "academic" example.